# How do I flatten an array of arrays in shopify liquid?

Tags: arrays, shopify, liquid

I've tried to loop through an array of arrays and capture the output using the below:

The array:

`["cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4"] ["cat1","cat2"] ["cat4"] ["cat5"]`

My attempt:

```
{% capture newCategories %}
  {% for categoryArr in categories %}
    {% for category in categoryArr %}
      {{category}}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

newCategories --> // new array with items
```

and it still doesn't give me a flattened array, any ideas?

Comment: need to paste the actual code, it doesn't make any sense until

Comment: @Onkar the code i've tried is in the post

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to leverage the `concat` operator: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/concat/

Something like:

```
{% assign newCategories = '' | split: '' %}

{% for categoryArr in categories %}
    {% assign newCategories = newCategories | concat: categoryArr %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you add the full code? I've tried to work this in and there's no change to the final array. It doesn't seem to expand those inner arrays

Comment: That honestly ought to be the full code. Perhaps there is some issue with the structure of your `categories` array of arrays? Perhaps it is not being stored as an array or something like that?

Comment: There is a syntax error in the code. I believe `split ''` should be `split: ''` instead.

Comment: @AndrásGeiszl I believe you're right - I'll update the original snippet to reflect, thanks for catching!